# In C++, is it possible to reconcile stack-based memory management and polymorphism?

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, stack

I love declaring variables on the stack, especially when using the standard container. Each time you avoid a `new`, you avoid a potential memory leak.

I also like using polymorphism, ie class hierarchies with virtual functions. However, it seems these features are a bit incompatible: you can't do:

```
std::vector<BaseType> vec;
vec.push_back(DerivedType())
```

or at least it seems you would lose the polymorphic nature of the object you push in.

So, is there any way to reconcile stack-based memory management and the use of virtual functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the obvious answer:

```
std::vector<BaseType*> vec;
DerivedType d;
vec.push_back(&d);
```

But probably not what you intended. `d` and `vec` better die at the same time; if `vec` outlives `d` you've got a bad pointer.

I think what you really want is something like Boost [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html):

```
boost::ptr_vector<BaseType> vec;
vec.push_back(new DerivedType());
```

So you don't have to worry about leaks. The pointer containers were made specifically for the task of easing use and storage of polymorphic objects.

Comment: Your first example won't even compile, I cannot see a remark for this being a non-real code example; so I expect you meant something like std::vector<BaseType*>, which of course would fail as soon as you pass a copy of vec to an outer scope...  Still, +1 for the pointer-containers.

Comment: @Neil @gimpf: Oops yeah. I just copied the OP's snippet for time, didn't see it was "incorrect".

Answer (score 3):

In this case you not only lose polymorphic nature, you [slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) your derived-type object to base type object.

But you can use smart pointers instead.

```
std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<BaseType> > vec;
vec.push_back(std::tr1::shared_ptr<BaseType>(new DerivedType()));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `std::vector` variable on the stack ***dynamic memory allocation does happen*** for the vector's internal array. It's not necessarily from the heap though. The second template parameter of `std::vector` defaults to `std::allocator` that you can replace with your own custom one.

For managing polymorphic types there are tool like [`boost::smart_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) and [boost intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a smart pointer implementation either from Boost libraries or the POCO  C++ libraries http://www.pocoproject.org.

```
include "Poco/SharedPtr.h"

include "vector.h"

class Base
{
   protected:
      std::string somestring;
   public:
      Base()
      {
          somestring = "Hello";
      }
      virtual void Method1() { 
          std::cout << "Method1 " << somestring.c_str() << std::endl;
      }
      virtual ~Base()
      {
          std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
      }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
      void Method1() 
      { 
          std::cout << "overriden Method1 " << somestring.c_str() << std::endl;
      }
     ~Derived() 
     {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
     }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Poco::SharedPtr<Base> > someVector;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++)
    {
        Poco::SharedPtr<Base> obj = new Base();
        Poco::SharedPtr<Derived> dObj = new Derived();
        someVector.push_back(obj);
        someVector.push_back(dObj);
    }

    std::vector<Poco::SharedPtr<Base> >::iterator itr = someVector.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < someVector.size(); i++)
    {
        someVector[i]->Method1();   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your main interest is in preventing memory leaks, you may wish to look at smart pointers. I would recommend [Boost's Smart Pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr) .

Comment: Good general advice, but for large collections the smart pointers incur a large overhead; which will be ignorable, most of the time, though.

Answer (score 1):

The conflict is not between polymorphism and (heap or stack) allocation, since standard containers normally allocate their elements on the heap.

The conflict is between polymorphism and (value or reference) semantics. Polymorphism needs the additional level of indirection brought by reference semantics to work, but standard containers have value semantics.

The solution, as already mentioned in the other answers, is to store objects whose values are references to other objects, the simpler of which are pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers are best solution as comments suggest.

Another technique -- if you're using polymorphism mostly to hide your class's implementation details -- is [Pimpl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) [idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm).